Shutdown symlinked to systemctl in an unexpected way, how is it achieved?
I'm looking in /usr/sbin/shutdown and seeing
$ ll /usr/sbin
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  14 Apr  8 20:51 shutdown -> /bin/systemctl*

I'm used to symlinks being the exact same command as their link, however when I run the --help commands for shutdown and systemctl they're different.
How is this type of symlinking achieved?
I'm familiar with how to do it with a wrapper script but then the actual symlink wouldn't be needed as the linked command is called from within the wrapper script.
nick ~  : shutdown --help
shutdown [OPTIONS...] [TIME] [WALL...]

Shut down the system.

Options:
     --help      Show this help
  -H --halt      Halt the machine
  -P --poweroff  Power-off the machine
  -r --reboot    Reboot the machine
  -h             Equivalent to --poweroff, overridden by --halt
  -k             Don't halt/power-off/reboot, just send warnings
     --no-wall   Don't send wall message before halt/power-off/reboot
  -c             Cancel a pending shutdown

See the shutdown(8) man page for details.



nick ~  : systemctl --help
systemctl [OPTIONS...] COMMAND ...

Query or send control commands to the system manager.

Unit Commands:
  list-units [PATTERN...]             List units currently in memory
  list-sockets [PATTERN...]           List socket units currently in memory,
                                      ordered by address
  list-timers [PATTERN...]            List timer units currently in memory,
                                      ordered by next elapse

.....more


A system running on busybox will have many such links. The general pattern is to dispatch to the relevant code based on the command name ( cf. https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/libbb/appletlib.c#n1107 , https://sourceware.org/git/?p=bzip2.git;a=blob;f=bzip2.c#l1862 , etc )

Notionally, examining command name and changing behaviour is no different from checking if --help or -r was passed and changing behaviour but there are situations where command-name may not reliably be available

I've done this a lot.
What's going on is the binary checks argv[0] to check what it should behave as. This binary is designed to have multiple behaviors.
Don't go doing this for random binaries; only binaries that say this works actually handle it.
